# How can we get dynamic dropdowns to display specific options based on the previous dropdown, and be able to randomize the output?

Tags: php, jquery, imagick

I'm posting on behalf of a coder I work for (her screenreader doesn't play nice with most coding sites; I will be forwarding responses to her to try and then reporting back the results) regarding setting up a layered image in Imagick using jQuery and PHP to select multiple dynamic dropdowns, with some of the dropdowns being dependent on a previous one (this is for a pet simulation site's pet creation tool, so for example, the first selection is Species, and then different eye colors, markings, etc, are available based on the chosen species; the Gender selection doesn't affect the displayed image or other dropdowns but does affect the output of the creation tool, and the Background selection DOES affect the image and also the output but not any of the other dropdowns). Selecting one-dropdown-at-a-time is kind of working, though the image isn't refreshing on every selection like it should be. There's also a 'Randomize' button that should select a random species, gender, markings, etc, within specific parameters (say, only 1 - 5 markings, but a random number of them and random individual markings choices). The Randomize button isn't working at all, it only references the hard-coded dropdowns and so fails to produce an image successfully.

You can see the tool here: https://www.vulpesvatic.com/demo

This is the current code (sorry it's so huge, our coder has a tendency to work in long formats, suggestions to compress it are welcome):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

{{-- Page Title --}}
@section('title')
Demo
@endsection

{{-- Page Content --}}
@section('content')
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode($output) }}" alt="Fox" id="fox" />
</div>
    <form action="{{ route('demo.process') }}" method="post" id="demo" role="form">
<h2>The Basics</h2>
<div>
    <label for="background_id">
        Background:
    </label>
    <select name="background_id" id="background_id" required>
        @foreach ($backgrounds as $b)
        <option value="{{ $b->id }}">{{ ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $b->name)) }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="species_id">
        Species:
    </label>
    <select name="species_id" id="species_id" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
        @foreach ($species as $s)
        <option value="{{ $s->id }}">{{ ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $s->name)) }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="gender">
        Gender:
    </label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Gender</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
    </select>
    </div>
<div>
    <label for="fur_color_id">
        Fur:
    </label>
    <select name="fur_color_id" id="fur_color_id" class="options" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="skin_color_id">
        Skin:
    </label>
    <select name="skin_color_id" id="skin_color_id" class="options" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="claws_color_id">
        Claws:
    </label>
    <select name="claws_color_id" id="claws_color_id" class="options" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="eyes_left_color_id">
        Left Eye:
    </label>
    <select name="eyes_left_color_id" id="eyes_left_color_id" class="options" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="eyes_right_color_id">
        Right Eye:
    </label>
    <select name="eyes_right_color_id" id="eyes_right_color_id" class="options" required>
<option selected disabled>Select a Species</option>
    </select>
</div>
<h2>Markings</h2>
    <div id="markings">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="add_marking" id="add_marking">
            Add Marking
        </button>
    </div>
<h2>Tail Markings</h2>
<div id="tail_markings">
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" name="add_tail_marking" id="add_tail_marking">
        Add Tail Marking
    </button>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" name="randomize" id="randomize">
        Randomize
    </button>
</div>
@if (auth()->check())
<div>
    <button type="button" name="create" id="create" disabled>
        Create
    </button>
</div>
@endif
<div>
    <button type="button" name="reset" id="reset">
        Reset
    </button>
</div>
</form>
@endsection

{{-- Page JS --}}
@section('js')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

// Global variables.
    var page = {
        check: false,
        isLoading: false
    };

// Populate the basic dropdowns according to the selected species.
    $('select#species_id').on('change', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{ route('demo.basics') }}",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        option: $(this).val()
    },
    success: function(response) {

// Fur colors.
        $('select#fur_color_id').empty();
$.each(response.demo_fur_colors, function(key, value) {
    $('select#fur_color_id').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
});

// Skin colors.
        $('select#skin_color_id').empty();
$.each(response.demo_skin_colors, function(key, value) {
    $('select#skin_color_id').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
});

// Claws colors.
        $('select#claws_color_id').empty();
$.each(response.demo_claw_colors, function(key, value) {
    $('select#claws_color_id').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
});

// Eyes left colors.
        $('select#eyes_left_color_id').empty();
$.each(response.demo_eye_colors, function(key, value) {
    $('select#eyes_left_color_id').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
});

// Eyes right colors.
        $('select#eyes_right_color_id').empty();
$.each(response.demo_eye_colors, function(key, value) {
    $('select#eyes_right_color_id').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
});

// Process..
if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
    processDemo();
}

    }
});

});

$('select.options', 'input.options').on('change', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

var marking_count = 0;
$('button#add_marking').on('click', function(){
    if (marking_count < 5) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{ route('demo.markings') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            option: $('#species_id').val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('div#markings').append(
                '<div class="marking_options">'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="marking'+marking_count+'">'+
                'Marking:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<select name="marking[]" id="marking'+marking_count+'" class="marking options">'+
                '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="marking_color'+marking_count+'">'+
                'Color:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<select name="marking_color[]" id="marking_color'+marking_count+'" class="marking_color options">'+
                '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="marking_opacity'+marking_count+'">'+
                'Opacity:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<input type="range" name="marking_opacity[]" value="1" step="0.01" min="0" max="1" id="marking_opacity'+marking_count+'" class="marking_opacity options" />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<button type="button" name="remove_marking" id="remove_marking'+marking_count+'" class="remove_marking">'+
                'Remove Marking'+
                '</button>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'
            );

// Markings.
            $('select#marking'+marking_count).empty();
$('select#marking'+marking_count).append('<option selected disabled>Select a Marking</option>');
    $.each(response.demo_markings, function(key, value) {
        $('select#marking'+marking_count).append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
    });

// Prevent duplicates.
    $('select.marking').each(function(){
        $('select.marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).data('index', this.value);
        $('select.marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', false);
    });

// Markings colors.
            $('select#marking_color'+marking_count).empty();
$('select#marking_color'+marking_count).append('<option selected disabled>Select a Marking Color</option>');
    $.each(response.demo_fur_colors, function(key, value) {
        $('select#marking_color'+marking_count).append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
    });

        }
    });

    marking_count ++;
}
else {
    alert('You can not add any more markings.');
}
});

$('div#markings').on('change', 'select.marking', function(event){
    $('select.marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $('select.marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', false);
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#markings').on('change', 'select.marking_color', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#markings').on('change', 'input.marking_opacity', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#markings').on('click', 'button.remove_marking', function(event){
    var marking = $(this).closest('div.marking_options').find('select.marking').val();
    $('select.marking').each(function(){
        $(this).find('option[value="'+marking+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $(this).closest('div.marking_options').remove();
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
    marking_count --;
});

var tail_marking_count = 0;
$('button#add_tail_marking').on('click', function(){
    if (tail_marking_count < 5) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{ route('demo.tail-markings') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            option: $('#species_id').val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('div#tail_markings').append(
                '<div class="tail_marking_options">'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="tail_marking'+tail_marking_count+'">'+
                'Tail Marking:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<select name="tail_marking[]" id="tail_marking'+tail_marking_count+'" class="tail_marking options">'+
                '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="tail_marking_color'+tail_marking_count+'">'+
                'Color:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<select name="tail_marking_color[]" id="tail_marking_color'+tail_marking_count+'" class="tail_marking_color options">'+
                '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<label for="tail_marking_opacity'+tail_marking_count+'">'+
                'Opacity:'+
                '</label>'+
                '<input type="range" name="tail_marking_opacity[]" value="1" step="0.01" min="0" max="1" id="tail_marking_opacity'+tail_marking_count+'" class="tail_marking_opacity options" />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<button type="button" name="remove_tail_marking" id="remove_tail_marking'+tail_marking_count+'" class="remove_tail_marking">'+
                'Remove Tail Marking'+
                '</button>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'
            );
// Tail markings.
            $('select#tail_marking'+tail_marking_count).empty();
$('select#tail_marking'+tail_marking_count).append('<option selected disabled>Select a Tail Marking</option>');
    $.each(response.demo_tail_markings, function(key, value) {
        $('select#tail_marking'+tail_marking_count).append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
    });

// Prevent duplicates.
    $('select.tail_marking').each(function(){
        $('select.tail_marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).data('index', this.value);
        $('select.tail_marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', false);
    });

// Tail marking colors.
            $('select#tail_marking_color'+tail_marking_count).empty();
$('select#tail_marking_color'+tail_marking_count).append('<option selected disabled>Select a Tail Marking Color</option>');
    $.each(response.demo_fur_colors, function(key, value) {
        $('select#tail_marking_color'+tail_marking_count).append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+ucwords(str_replace(value.name))+'</option>');
    });

        }
    });

    tail_marking_count ++;
    }
    else {
        alert('You can not add any more tail markings.');
    }
});

$('div#tail_markings').on('change', 'select.tail_marking', function(event){
    $('select.tail_marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $('select.tail_marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', false);
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#tail_markings').on('change', 'select.tail_marking_color', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#tail_markings').on('change', 'input.tail_marking_opacity', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
});

$('div#tail_markings').on('click', 'button.remove_tail_marking', function(event){
    var tail_marking = $(this).closest('div.tail_marking_options').find('select.tail_marking').val();
    $('select.tail_marking').each(function(){
        $(this).find('option[value="'+tail_marking+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $(this).closest('div.tail_marking_options').remove();
    if (event.originalEvent != undefined) {
        processDemo();
    }
    tail_marking_count --;
});

$('button#randomize').on('click', function(){
    $('button.remove_marking').trigger('click');
    $('button.remove_tail_marking').trigger('click');
    markings = ~~(Math.random() * 5);
    for (m = 0; m < markings; m ++) {
        $('button#add_marking').trigger('click');
    }
    tail_markings = ~~(Math.random() * 5);
    for (t = 0; t < tail_markings; t ++) {
        $('button#add_tail_marking').trigger('click');
    }
    $('select.options').each(function(){
        var $options = $(this).find('option:enabled');
        random = ~~(Math.random() * $options.length);
        $options.eq(random).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
    });
    $('input.options').each(function(){
        random = ~~(Math.random() * 100) / 100;
        $(this).val(random).trigger('change');
    });
    processDemo();
});

$('button#reset').click(function(){
    $('form#demo').trigger('reset');
    processDemo();
});

$('button#create').on('click', function(){
    $('button#create').data('clicked', true);
    $('button#create').prop('disabled', true);
    processDemo();
});

    function processDemo() {
        if (!page.check) {
            page.check = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.check = false;
        }, 500);
        $('img#fox').prop('src', 'images/assets/foxes/misc/loading.gif');
        var foxData = {
            background_id: $('select#background_id').val(),
            species_id: $('select#species_id').val(),
            gender: $('select#gender').val(),
            fur_color_id: $('select#fur_color_id').val(),
            skin_color_id: $('select#skin_color_id').val(),
            claws_color_id: $('select#claws_color_id').val(),
            eyes_left_color_id: $('select#eyes_left_color_id').val(),
            eyes_right_color_id: $('select#eyes_left_color_id').val(),
            markings: $('select.marking').serializeArray(),
            markings_color: $('select.marking_color').serializeArray(),
            markings_opacity: $('input.marking_opacity').serializeArray(),
            tail_markings: $('select.tail_marking').serializeArray(),
            tail_markings_color: $('select.tail_marking_color').serializeArray(),
            tail_markings_opacity: $('input.tail_marking_opacity').serializeArray(),
            create: 'no'
        };
        if ($('button#create').data('clicked')) {
            foxData.create = 'yes';
            $('button#create').data('clicked', false);
        }
        JSON.stringify(foxData);
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{ route('demo.process') }}",
    dataType: "json",
        data: foxData,
    success: function(data){
        if (foxData.create == 'no') {
            $('img#fox').prop('src', 'data:image/png;base64,'+data.image);
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        }
}
});
}
}

// Replace _ in the given string.
function str_replace(str) {
    return str.replace(/\_/g, ' ');
}

function ucwords (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

    });
</script>
@endsection
```

So yeah, basically need help figuring out why it's not working, we've asked several people and are at a loss. Someone suggested using event triggers but didn't explain anything beyond that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for posting question in much better way, will help community to understand easily.

Comment: eek, sorry, I've never posted here before. I'll talk to my coder and see if we can come up with a better post!  a big part of the problem is that we have NO IDEA where in the code the issue is, but we can try process of elimination.